# C# - saving user selected outlook folder

Tags: c#, outlook

I have a basic C# form where the user select a folder from outlook (using [`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application.Session.PickFolder()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._namespace.pickfolder.aspx))

I want this folder to be saved so every time the user opens the form, the last select folder will be restored.

How can that be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user picks the folder via [`PickFolder()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._namespace.pickfolder.aspx), store the [`Folder.EntryID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.entryid.aspx) and [`Folder.StoreID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.storeid.aspx) of the selected folder. You can then use [`Session.GetFolderFromID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._namespace.getfolderfromid.aspx) to retrieve the previously selected folder.

See [this MSDN example for reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184616.aspx).

```cs
Outlook.Folder folder = Application.Session.PickFolder() as Outlook.Folder;
Outlook.Folder folderFromID = Application.Session.GetFolderFromID(folder.EntryID, folder.StoreID) as Outlook.Folder;
```

Comment: Can you give an example on how to save and restore it? Where is it saved?